# Conversation with C# Speech Library

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I have the following code using the Speech Recognition library:

```
var listen = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
var reader = new Choices(File.ReadLines(@"C:\words.txt")
listen.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(reader)));
listen.SpeechRecognized += listen_SpeechRecognized;
listen.SpeechRecognitionRejected += listen_SpeechRecognitionRejected;
listen.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
listen.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

And I have an event listener like this...

```
static void listen_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {

            var talk = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            if (e.Result.Text == "Search Stock Symbol") 
            {
                talk.Speak("What symbol?");
                //Do I have to create another event listener?
                //a Listener .. symbol = a.Result.Text
                //talk.Speak(GetQuote(symbol))
            {
        }
```

Would I have to create an event listener for every portion of the "conversation"? Is there a better way if that is the case?

Example Conversation:

- Me: Search Stock Symbol
- Computer: What Symbol?
- Me: AAPL
- Computer: Apple is trading at ....

Answer (score 3):

Nope, just the one, then vary what you do depending on what text was received. In some code before:

```
    List<string> stockSymbols = new List<string>();
    stockSymbols.Add("AAPL");
```

Then

```
    string lastSpeechInput;

    static void listen_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        var talk = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        switch (e.Result.Text) {
            case "Search Stock Symbol":
                talk.Speak("What symbol?");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (stockSymbols.Contains(e.Result.Text) && lastSpeechInput == "Search Stock Symbol") {
            talk.Speak(getStockPrice(e.Result.Text);
        }

        lastSpeechInput = e.Result.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Would this work if "AAPL" is not in dictionary.txt? I've tried your code and it doesn't appear to work. This is the code I tried: http://pastebin.com/Jpkz8Xu9

Comment: Oh I see, fixed the lack of default in switch-case. Also note the made up function getStockPrice

Comment: Yea i know the function is made up. But the problem with this is that e.Result.Text will always be == "Search Stock Symbol". This will only work if "Search Stock Symbol" is in the list.

Comment: The question isn't how to iterate through a list and test for the presence of strings. That's just an example. I'm really only solving the question here, that's filler to show you what you do *potentially* do. What logic you do within that is up to you. The if statement will get fired if you say any word In the list (.Contains()) after saying search stock price.